# QGIS modeler to filter feature and crop it

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm starting to discover QGIS modeler and its utilities and I was wondering if I can filter a feature within a layer and crop it with a number input.

[image: Layer features]

What I'm trying to do is give an input for the field "N_Cadastro" and it automatically crops only that feature.

Is it possible?

[image: Fields within the layer]

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, i got it myself. Here's what I used.

[image]

[image]